# onclick using databinding in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to implement data binding in a Fragment but it's not working, the same code is working in Activity.

Fragment class

```
    final FragmentHomeBinding fragmentHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    fragmentHomeBinding.setVariable(BR.homeViewModel, homeViewModel);
    HomeEventHandler homeEventHandler = new HomeEventHandler(getActivity());
    fragmentHomeBinding.setHandler(homeEventHandler);
```

EventHandlerClass

```
HomeEventHandler(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    Log.e("DB", "onButtonClick: ");
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.frag_home_ll_stock:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, StockCheckActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and finally the xml file

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="fragment"
        type="com.poc.ui.home.HomeFragment"/>

    <variable
        name="handler"
        type="com.poc.ui.home.HomeEventHandler"/>

</data>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:onClick="@{view->handler.onButtonClick(view)}"
                    android:id="@+id/frag_home_ll_stock"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/grey_25"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
                    <!--
                    -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/frag_home_tv_op4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:text="@string/w_stock_check"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/frag_home_iv_op4"
                        android:layout_width="72dp"
                        android:layout_height="72dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_stock" />


                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the below line from your `Fragment`

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

And If you need the view, you can pass with a parameter like below

```
android:onClick="@{(view) -> handler.onButtonClick(view)}"
```

Your `LinearLayout` should be like the following.

```
 <LinearLayout
   android:onClick="@{(view)->handler.onButtonClick(view)}"
   android:id="@+id/frag_home_ll_stock"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:background="@color/grey_25"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="16dp">
```

Comment: try to remove this line `View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);`

Comment: that was the issue, absolute idiotic from me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 <ImageView
    android:onClick="@{(view) -> handler.onButtonClick()}"
    android:id="@+id/frag_home_iv_op3"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_report" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <variable
    name="HomeviewModel"
    type="com.poc.ui.home.HomeviewModel"/>  //  exact path
  you need to declare the viewmodel variable 

  android:onClick="@{(v) ->  homeViewModel.buttonClicked(v, true)}"

  if you are passing the parameter the function also should also contain same parameter

  for e.g,
  private void buttonClicked(View view, boolean value){
        // your code
   }
```

your method should look like this .

Comment: I have updated the xml can you please look at it again, thanks